# Can anyone explain the length parameter to fgets() in PHP?

Tags: php

Assume that I have a file named data.txt with the contents "Blah Blah !".
So when I use the code below

```
$hnd=fopen('data.txt','r');
echo fgets($hnd,2);
```

it displays just one character "B" instead of "Bl". Later I read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) stating:

> **length**
>
> Reading ends when `length - 1` bytes have been read, or a newline (which is included in the return value), or an EOF (whichever comes first). If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line.

Can anyone explain to me why it is this way? I mean why is it `length-1` and not `length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C `fgets()` function reads `length - 1` bytes, because it has to add a terminating zero to turn the data into a proper string.

My best guess is that PHP's `fgets()` exhibits the same behaviour because it is either:

- a legacy from the bad old days when PHP functions were little more that wrappers around the corresponding C functions, and string functions were binary unsafe (eg. strings could not contain embedded NUL characters). Changing the behaviour of the `fgets()` function would introduce new bugs in existing programs. Or,
- a deliberate decision to make the PHP function compatible with the C function to avoid unnecessary surprises.

or both.

---

Interestingly, it looks like PHP internally adds a terminating zero when storing string values, for example in [`_php_stream_get_line()`](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=main/streams/streams.c;hb=8f0dbe235597626c07167f8f93838335e5cad2e5#l987) (called from [`fgets()`](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=ext/standard/file.c;hb=8f0dbe235597626c07167f8f93838335e5cad2e5#l1028)) and [`zend_string_init()`](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=Zend/zend_string.h;hb=8f0dbe235597626c07167f8f93838335e5cad2e5#l136).

Since [`_zend_string`](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=Zend/zend_types.h;h=09560943e574ef0095a459019502afcd8785ced8;hb=HEAD#l149) objects store the string length anyway, it shouldn't be necessary to store the terminating zero, unless there are still binary unsafe functions in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP, like many C-derivatives count from 0, and not from 1. They have [Zero-based numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)

Eg for arrays: An array of length/size `n` has `0` to `n - 1`, elements.

i.e. `0, 1, 2 , 3, 4 .... n-1`

So an array of length 5 has elements `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`

So you will find that whether reading byte, strings, arrays... they always reference the to the `(n-1)th element` or marker, for an n-size structure

Answer (score -2):

Please use following code for your raised questionarries

```
$hnd=fopen('E:\\data.txt','r');
echo fgets($hnd,2);
```